# Creating unknown number of multiple C++ objects automatically

Tags: c++, oop

I would like to know C++ way of creating multiple indefinite number of objects (0..n) automatically. The use case is as below:

Let say I have a script that a user has to enter related data (width, length, height) that later on Box class will contain those data.

```
Box
{ 
    ...
    ...
    double width;
    double length;
    double height;
    ...
    ...
}
```

The script looks like:

```
<id="width" value="1"/>
<id="length" value="3"/>
<id="height" value="3"/>

<id="width2" value="3"/>
<id="length2" value="3"/>
<id="height2" value="4"/>

<id="width3" value="2"/>
<id="length3" value="3"/>
<id="height3" value="3"/>
```

In other words, how can I instantiate those object which number of the objects is not known in advance, rather, it depends on how many box information (width and so on) is entered by the user.

Also, is there any design pattern for that?

Comment: why isn't this just a loop calling new Box(width, length, height) many times?

Comment: But how do we deduce, how many times it should loop?

Comment: loop until the file is finished

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose you want `n` objects type `Box`

```
Box **array = new Box*[n];
for(int i = 0; i < n; i += 1) {
    array[i] = new Box();
}
```

**UPDATE #1**

if you want a variable length list, you can try:

- [Vectors](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/)
- [Linked Lists](http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/LACRko23/)

Comment: The issue here is that this is assuming there only n boxes

Comment: n is a variable not a fixed number of objects. Therefore, n here should be fine.

Comment: @alfa_80 My answer offers a dynamic memory allocation, so `n` can be variable at run-time and it works fine

Comment: But you do need to know what n is in advance.

Comment: the code fragment will not compile, unless `Box` can be casted to `Box*` in which case it will compile, run, and leak. Do yourself a favor and learn C++ before misleading people less experienced than you

Comment: Yes, I agree with @Ferruccio, that I need to know in advance.

Comment: @pqnet which `Box` should be cast to `Box *`?

Comment: At least test your code before submitting. At line 3 you have an assignment where on the left side you have a `Box&` lvalue, on right side you have a `Box*` rvalue. This won't compile

Comment: @pqnet ops! you're right it was just a typo, updated!

Comment: well, now it is just bad design.

Comment: @pqnet why is it bad design?

Comment: Because 1) you are using manually allocated memory, and twice at it by allocating an array of pointers, which will require you to do manual bookkeeping of what you have to `delete` later, 2) you are implementing ad-hoc something that is already on the standard library (`vector`), and there's never a reason to write again something that already exists, 3) why using pointers to pointers when writing `new Box[n]`, without any loop after that, would have been enough to obtain a similar result?

Comment: The idea/algorithm is nice but not the choice of not choosing std::vector.

Answer (score 6):

Use `std::vector`

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/

It will allow to add an unknown number of objects to it, and works like an array

Answer (score 2):

You cannot during runtime add new members to your class based on XML. The best you can do is to you `std::map` in your class, which will map the ids to values. Something like

```
class Box
{
  std::map<std::string, int> values;
...
```

and then e.g. in Box constructor

```
values["width"] = 1;
values["width2] = 3;
```

Obviously instead of hard coding it you may read the values from XML and add them.

Answer (score 1):

The obvious is that in first place you have to parse the xml file. All other answers assumes you already know how to do that. Here I will complement QuinnFTW's answer and also give you a link to [Parsing xml with Boost](http://akrzemi1.wordpress.com/2011/07/13/parsing-xml-with-boost/). Why? Well, if you knew how to obtain a list of objects from the xml, you were not asking this question.

And, complementing QuinnFTW's answer a code sample using [std::vector](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Box { 
    double with, length, height; 
    Box():with(0), length(0), height(0) {}
};

typedef std::vector<Box> box_list_t;


int main()
{

    Box a, b, c;
    // Create the vector.
    box_list_t box_list;

    box_list.push_back(a);  // Add a to the vector;
    box_list.push_back(b);  // Add b to the vector;
    box_list.push_back(c);  // Add c to the vector;

    box_list[0].with = 0;   // Change the with of a to 0;
    cout << box_list[1].with << endl; // Prints b.with. Have not been initialized.


    return 0;
}
```